# If two modules both defined the same menu path in 'hook_menu', which one Drupal will choose?

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

For example, "moduleone" defines the path 'admin/hello', which output `print_moduleone_stuff()`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function moduleone_menu() {
  $items['admin/hello'] = array(
    'title' => 'Module One Hello World',
    'page callback' => print_moduleone_stuff,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

"moduletwo" defines the path 'admin/hello', which output `print_moduletwo_stuff()`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function moduletwo_menu() {
  $items['admin/hello'] = array(
    'title' => 'Module Two Hello World',
    'page callback' => print_moduletwo_stuff,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Both modules defined 'admin/hello' path for different result. With these two module enabled, how does Drupal select one than another? How does Drupal solve the conflict?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function invoking `hook_menu()` is [menu_router_build()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_router_build/7), called by [menu_rebuild()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7). It contains the following code.

```
  foreach (module_implements('menu') as $module) {
    $router_items = call_user_func($module . '_menu');
    if (isset($router_items) && is_array($router_items)) {
      foreach (array_keys($router_items) as $path) {
        $router_items[$path]['module'] = $module;
      }
      $callbacks = array_merge($callbacks, $router_items);
    }
  }
  // Alter the menu as defined in modules, keys are like user/%user.
  drupal_alter('menu', $callbacks);
```

If there are two modules defining the same route, the last module in the array returned by [`module_implements()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_implements/7) will override the value defined from the other modules.

The second parameter required by `module_implements()` is defined as:

> `$sort` By default, modules are ordered by weight and filename, settings this option to `TRUE`, module list will be ordered by module name.

Since `menu_router_build()` doesn't pass the second parameter to `menu_implements()`, the function is using the default value for that parameter. This means the list of modules are ordered by their weight and filename; when two modules have the same weight, the first module that appears in the list is the one that alphabetically comes first.

Furthermore, any module implementing [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7.x) can alter the order the hooks are invoked.

For this reason, you should not assume to know in which order the hooks are invoked.
If the purpose of the code is altering the route implemented by another module, for example because a route should be removed when a second module is installed and enabled, the code should use [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). If you are trying to understand which module would "win" in the case of route conflicts, I would rather avoid such route conflict, and define a route that is not already defined from another module.

If then you are implementing `hook_menu_alter()`, and you want to be sure your module is executed last, to be the module that effectively overrides a route, you should implement `hook_module_implements_alter()` too.

```
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'menu_alter') {
    // Move mymodule_menu_alter() to the end of the list. module_implements()
    // iterates through $implementations with a foreach loop which PHP iterates
    // in the order that the items were added, so to move an item to the end of
    // the array, we remove it and then add it.
    $group = $implementations['mymodule'];
    unset($implementations['mymodule']);
    $implementations['mymodule'] = $group;
  }
}
```

Comment: so clear and helpful, thanks. also thanks for mentioning the usage hook_menu_alter() in this case.

Comment: what if two modules define same path in hook_menu_alter()?  same rules applied?

Comment: `hook_menu_alter()` is not used to define new menus, but to alter the existing ones. If two modules alter the same menu, the alteration that survives is the one from the module that is executed for last.

Comment: Great answer, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Whichever module has a lower `weight` value in the `system` table will be called first, so the module with the higher `weight` value will 'win' in this case.

If the weights are the same for two (or more) modules I believe there is no specific ordering done other than the ordering that comes directly from the MySQL table (I could be wrong about that though).

As the return results from the invoke of `hook_menu` are just put into a single array of menu items there will never be a 'conflict' as such, the results from later calls to `hook_menu` will simply override those from the earlier calls.

Comment: According to _Pro Drupal Development_, modules with equal weight are called in alphabetical order by their system name.

Comment: What reported by that book is correct: The list of modules implementing a hook is generally sorted by weight and alphabetically; it would not be sorted if `module_implements()` gets `FALSE` as second parameter, but functions like `module_invoke_all()` calls it with just a parameter.

Comment: My previous comment is not completely exact. What I report in my answer is correct.